# How to find draw on System.Windows.Controls.*?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, drawing, draw

I'm digging in a WPF application written in C#.

I need to draw a selection rectangle, like the one we use to select more than one item (like files in a folder).

I have a few objects, which are of types System.Windows.Controls.Control, System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl and System.Windows.FrameworkElement.

I assume, I need to override event like onPaint, onDraw or reDraw/rePaint. 

Can I use those object to draw rectangle and how?

Comment: Please, tell me what information to add and I will do it.

Comment: You don't have a WinForms application, you have a WPF application.  These two things are **not** the same...

Comment: OK. I'll learn how to draw in WPF first, then came back.

Comment: This is also known as "rubberbanding"...should help you with searching.

Answer (score 0):

WPF and WinForms are completely different from this aspect. In WinForms you can override `OnPaint` to draw anything directly to the drawing context by using the `Graphics` object in the event handler.

In WPF, there is an `OnRender` method, which seemingly behaves similarly as OnPaint:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush  = new SolidColorBrush();
    mySolidColorBrush.Color = Colors.LimeGreen;
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 10);
    Rect myRect = new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    dc.DrawRectangle(mySolidColorBrush, myPen, myRect);
}
```

However, in WPF every visual element is an object, you cannot draw directly anything. What the "drawing" methods of `DrawingContext` actually do, is just inserting objects into the visual tree, which will be rendered later along with the other elements.

Using `OnRender` is usually not the best idea, and it has a [really bad performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2009/09/08/onrender-is-not-as-cheap-as-onpaint.aspx) comparing to the fast `Graphics` operations. In WPF it is better to use custom controls or templates instead.